# How to disable jQuery tabs when customizing the theme

Tags: customization, wp-enqueue-script

Regarding this yet unsolved [bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23225), how can I disable jQuery Tabs from the frontend when using the theme customizer?

Comment: Does this comment bump my question?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/02/17/using-jquery-ui-tabs-with-the-base-tag/).

Just add this js code:

```
var makeTabs = function(selector) {
    $( selector )
        .find( "ul a" ).each( function() {
            var href = $( this ).attr( "href" ),
                newHref = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname +
                    window.location.pathname + href;

            if ( href.indexOf( "#" ) == 0 ) {
                $( this ).attr( "href", newHref );
            }
        })
    $( selector ).tabs();
};

makeTabs( "#tabs" );
```

Comment: The problems still exists actually. Any one knows an answer to my original question?